# Schedule download of new files on an FTP server

Tags: ubuntu, self-hosted, download-manager, ftp

There is an ftp server from which I want to download weekly the new files that were added to some folders.

Also I need something more advanced than wget or scp, the server conf is funny and I have to deal with it, wget and scp are unable to download the files, although FileZilla manages to.

The software should run on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) did the job ! With the "mirror" command.